# Copy directory from within Jar to location outside Jar

Tags: java, jar, directory, copy, exe

I'd like to distribute a program that copies an app (in other words, a directory with multiple subdirectories) from within the running Jar file to a location on the client's machine.

I've tried using FileUtils:

```
File TO = new File(ParentPath, "NewVersion.app");

try {
   File FROM = FileUtils.toFile(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("NewVersion.app"));

   FileUtils.copyDirectory(FROM, TO);

} catch (IOException ex) {…}
```

But all the above code does is create an empty folder named "NewVersion.app" and then throw an exception (Parameter FROM file is not a directory). Some other SO answers have suggested that files within Jars must be retrieved as input streams instead of files, but I'm not sure.

I'm going to package the jar into an exe anyway so the app to be copied doesn't necessarily have to sit within the Jar. Is there a better way to go about this or a fix for the above code?

Comment: You cannot list a directory in a .jar file.  Workarounds:  1. Include a text file in your .jar that lists every file (since you do know, after all, what you’re putting in your .jar file when you build it).  2.  Place all the files in a zip file, and embed that zip file in your .jar.

Comment: I'm going to build an EXE wrapper from the Jar with Launch4j anyway. Do you happen to know if it's possible to just put the directory in the EXE instead of putting it in the Jar? That might circumvent the Jar limitations.

Comment: I very much doubt it.  Launch4J does not create a new virtual file system, as far as I know.